# Woven stick style for 3d printing?

Tags: sculpting, 3d-printing

anyone got any ideas on how to do 3d models like so...

[image]

https://www.annaandthewillow.co.uk/gallery

but for 3d printing (ie faking it with textures won't really help).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A model with tiny strands like this would be impossible to print properly. I suggest you use sculpt mode and sculpt some detailed grooves onto the model in order to mimic the patterns of the strings.